How to prevent the "Visual Studio needs you to re-authenticate" error?
I often receive the error: Visual Studio needs you to re-authenticate. Please go to Tools->Options->Azure Services Authentication, and re-authenticate the account you want to use.. It occurs first thing when I start the day, or about every 2-3 days. Often it occurs when I change branches (using an external Git Repo client), or changing locations (such as work vs home location). After re-authenticating, everything works great (for 2-3 days). Speaking to my co-workers on the same project, they never get it.
I know how to solve it short-term (re-authenticate). But how can I prevent this constant re-authenticate issue? Why do I constantly get this error? What is the trigger???
Here's the .NET 8 code we use to connect. All packages are 100% up to date.
private SecretClient InitSecretClient()
{
    var keyVaultKey = configuration.GetValue<string>(KeyVaultConstants.BaseUrl);
    var clientId = configuration.GetValue<string>(KeyVaultConstants.ClientId);
    var credentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions() { ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId };
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(credentialOptions);
    
    var options = new SecretClientOptions()
    {
        Retry =
        {
            Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
            MaxRetries = 5,
            Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
        }
    };  
    
    return new SecretClient(keyVaultKey, credential, options);
}



Visual Studio needs you to re-authenticate. Please go to Tools->Options->Azure Services Authentication, and re-authenticate the account

To resolve the error, use the System web browser instead of Embedded browser auth in visual studio.

Navigate to the path %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio and delete visual studio cache.

Follow below steps to avoid being asked to re-enter your credentials:

Navigate to Tools -> Options -> Accounts in visual studio


Expand dropdown under Add and reauthenticate accounts, select System web browser.



Sign out and sign back in with your credentials again.
Restart Visual Studio, this helps to resolve the authentication issues.

I have used the below code to connect to Azure KeyVault and update the Secrets.
var kvuri = "<keyvault_uri>";
var clientId = "<client_id>";
var credentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions() { ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId };
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(credentialOptions);

var options = new SecretClientOptions()
{
 Retry =
    {
    Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
    MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
    MaxRetries = 5,
    Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
    }
};
var client=  new SecretClient(new Uri(kvuri), credential, options);
client.SetSecretAsync("secretname", "secretvalue");

Portal:

Able to connect to the Azure Key vault and update the Secret value:


References:
https://blog.jongallant.com/2021/08/visual-studio-re-enter-credentials/

Seemed to help for a couple weeks. The issue came back, and I usually re-authenticate once every day or two. This did not resolve the issue.

Have you selected System web browser?
